# Cubase 7 Macros for exporting

Tags: editing, cubase

Hi all I was wondering if any Cubase/Nuendo users could help me with a macro I am trying to create. I want to select all the slices of a track I have cut up and export them all as individual files. I have a bounce in place macro, so I can manually select the slices and bounce but I was hoping someone knew of a way to select an event on a track then bounce and move on to the next event etc?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can get it domne after reading this.

http://www.steinberg.net/en/support/tips_and_tricks/archive_2011/cubase_6_split_audio_files_july_2011.html

Comment: thanks for adding the link this is basically how I ended up doing it I posted a similar guide on another forum and forgot about this thread as it go next to no response. Apreaciate the link though thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://www.cubasetutorial.net/2013/02/07/bounce-in-place-in-cubase-by-using-this-macro/

Maybe it helps...still.

Comment: Could you include some details about the relevant information, in your own words, in your answer.  While the link may contain the information needed, there is no guarantee the link will stay valid and if it dies in the future, then this answer will have no value as it currently stands.